# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddApiVersioning' using dot net 5 for a webapi vs code project

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnet-api-versioning

I am trying to use versioning (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning) with dotnet 5 for a webapi project. I have added the nuget package but get the following error:

***'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddApiVersioning' and no accessible extension method 'AddApiVersioning' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

on this line:

```
services.AddApiVersioning();
```

in my Startup.cs

My .csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.4.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning" Version="4.1.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried to follow some examples, like [this one](https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/2020/09/18/versioning-rest-api-using-aspnet-core) and [this one](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3562355/how-to-use-api-versioning-in-aspnet-core.html) and [this one](https://dotnetdetail.net/implement-api-versioning-in-asp-net-core-5-web-api/), I should have the following 'using directive', which I have:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Is anybody having the same challenge? Is Versioning supported yet in .net 5?

Comment: Try this package. :) 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning) which is the API versioning package for ASP.NET Web API, the classic web API framework for .NET Framework.

You are using ASP.NET Core, so you will need the package [Microsoft.**AspNetCore.Mvc**.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning) instead. This package is also the one that’s mentioned in the tutorials you linked.

It’s very easy to confuse these packages however since they both come from the [same repository on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) which also produces a few additional packages for specialized use cases.

Comment: This seems to work, thank you, but I am getting a 'The type or namespace name 'ApiVersion' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)' error on 'new ApiVersion(1, 0)'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @lcj The `ApiVersion` type is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace, so you will need a `using` at the top for this. Try also invoking IntelliSense using `Ctrl + .` to help you fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

for .net6, i manually added from nuget

> [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning)

and added to the Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

it worked well. visual studio 2022 with .net6 combination has an issue like this. i had experienced this issue several times.

Comment: It seems the version 6 is released and the naming theme has changed. Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Mvc Github release: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/releases/tag/v6.0.0

Comment: i guess, sometimes code editors or IDEs could have these kind of issues. that is why i trust  real human experience from stackoverflow.com thank you stackoverflow team